# Holoviews Bars Ignoring .opts()

Tags: python, dataframe, holoviews

I am trying to pass .opts() arguments to style a holoviews .Bars graph, but all arguments are being ignored when passed. This results in the following error:
**WARNING:param.Bars02978: Use of **call** to set options will be deprecated in the next major release (1.14.0). Use the equivalent .opts method instead.**
I am on version 1.14.8.
How can I pass the .opts() so my graph can be styled appropriately?

````
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWP_h6WV8h0 Connecting multiple plots


from collections import defaultdict

import panel as pn

import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_bokeh
import bokeh
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, TableColumn, DataTable, DateEditor, IntEditor\
    , DateFormatter, NumeralTickFormatter, CustomJS, DatePicker, widgets
from bokeh.models import Panel, Tabs, Row
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import Column, layout

import hvplot.pandas

hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
renderer = renderer.instance(mode='server')

data = {
  "calories": [420],
  "duration": [50],
  "ggg": [60]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Missing Data': df[['calories']].sum(axis=1), 'Delayed Data': df[['duration']].sum(axis=1)
                       , 'Duplicate Data': df[['ggg']].sum(axis=1)})
print(df2)

bar_opts = opts.Bars(height=400, width=600, tools=["hover"], bgcolor="grey", xlabel="Wine Class", ylabel="Malic Acid", ylim=(0.0, 3.5))
bars = hv.Bars(pd.melt(df2.reset_index(), ['index']), ['index', 'variable'], 'value', label='dl_refined_analytics').opts(bar_opts)
bars.opts(height=400, width=600, tools=["hover"], bgcolor="grey", xlabel="Wine Class", ylabel="Malic Acid", ylim=(0.0, 3.5))
dmap = hv.DynamicMap(bars)

app = pn.Row(dmap)

app.show() ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was the intent behind `hv.DynamicMap(bars)`? I'm not sure why you'd want to pass the bars object to a DynamicMap constructor, and if you just use `app = pn.Row(bars)` instead of `app = pn.Row(dmap)` it should work fine.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering! The issue was within the IDE (pycharm) itself, a reboot actually fixed the issue.